# Shrinking volume for unallocated space for Dual Boot

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, windows-server-2016

May I shrink volume as per following scenario:

H: is a logical drive inside an extended partition. Without any impact on Windows and Data of H, can I use **Shrink Volume** to get an unallocated space so that I can install Windows Server 2016 for Dual-Boot?

As per attached picture, 1st, if I shrink logical drive, will that be any impact on logical drive data? 2nd, if I shrink logical drive, may I get unallocated space? If no, how to install another Windows for dual boot in this scenario?

[image]

Regards,

TekQ

Comment: Shrink which volume?  Please ask your question, within the body of the question, and be as specific as possible.  Worth pointing out, you are already as at the maximum amount of partitions for MBR, and Windows cannot be booted from an partition within a logical partition.